# Join strings in object name in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I need to join two strings in the name of the object in *for* loop in mongoose and expressjs like in example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    EnrollSessions.update({ CookieId: req.cookies.UserEnrollSession },
    {$set: {"Files.File"+i+".RealName": file.originalname},
function (err,data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
}
```

As a result i need update value of Files.File1.Realname, Files.File2.Realname.

Is it possible?
Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the for loop runs with `i` values 0 and 1 which would rename File0 and File1.

You can use `"Files.File"+ (i + 1) +".RealName"`.

A better approach would be to create the update object in the for loop and the send it to mongo afterwards.

```
let obj = {

};

for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    let name = "Files.File" + (i + 1) + ".RealName";
    obj[name] = file.originalname;
}   

    EnrollSessions.update({ CookieId: req.cookies.UserEnrollSession },
    {$set: obj},
function (err,data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
```

Or, if there are only 2 files you can hard code them by hand in the same update object instead of the for loop.